# Bypass ADFS Sign in/Home Realm Discovery page

Tags: adfs3.0

We are using ADFS (3.0) authentication in our web application. We have a scenario where a user can access a page without authentication however in an ADFS environment he gets the ADFS Sign in (Home Realm Discovery) page while trying to access that page from the web browser.

For e.g. if a user accesses http://www.test.com/prod/quickentry.aspx then the quick entry page should be displayed without any login or authentication page so that the user can create a basic record. The user needs to be able to do this without having to login to the application. This scenario works in a non ADFS environment but in an ADFS enabled environment the ADFS Sign in page is displayed.

In our application's web.config we have the following:

```
<location path="FederationMetadata">
 <system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

What we did was we only replaced "FederationMetadata" with "quickentry.aspx" and after that when we accessed the above link the quickentry page was displayed instead of the Sign In page. However on the quick entry page the fields and buttons are not displayed properly. It seems that the css is totally off on this page.

Is this the right way? Is something missing? If this is not the right way then please let me know if there is any way we can achieve the functionality to bypass the ADFS Sign in page and access the aspx page directly?

Thank you.

Comment: You should add another entry as you have now disallowed access to the metadata. Have you tried adding another entry to allow access to the .css folder?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked. I had to add 3 more entries but it worked. Right now I do not have an entry where the location path is FederationMetadata (as shown in my post). Would that be a problem or it isn't necessary? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wrote up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another entry in the web.config as you have now disallowed access to the metadata.

Convention is to allow access to metadata. This is useful e.g. when certificates rollover and other parties need the new certificate details.

Try adding another entry to allow access to the .css folder. (And any other folders that you are happy to allow access to without authentication).